# Jersey 1.19 returns 400 error passing an array into a web service

Tags: java, jersey

I have the following code in a simple Jersey service:

```
@Path("/form")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class FormValueService {
    private static final Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FormValueService.class);

    public FormValueService() {
        L.info("Creating FVS");
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/values")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String saveFormData(FormValue[] formValues) {
        String formId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        L.debug("Saving form {}", formId);
        for (FormValue fv : formValues) {
            L.debug("  Form value is {}", fv);
        }
        L.debug("Finished saving form {}", formId);
        return String.valueOf(Boolean.TRUE);

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/value")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String saveFormData(FormValue formValue) throws IOException {
        java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties"));
        String formId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        L.debug("Saving form {}", formId);
        L.debug("  Form value is {}", formValue);
        L.debug("Finished saving form {}", formId);
        return String.valueOf(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

The second method works great:

`curl -i -X POST -d '{"fieldName": "asdf", "fieldValue": "asdf", "fieldType": "CHAR"}' -H "Accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/ManageContact/rest/form/value`

No issues here, and I get the correct server messages.

The first method always returns a 400 error:

`curl -i -X POST -d '[{"fieldName": "asdf", "fieldValue": "asdf", "fieldType": "CHAR"}]' -H "Accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/ManageContact/rest/form/values`

This is running in Jetty, if that matters

EDIT Here is the application configuration:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class  ContactApplication extends Application{
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactApplication.class);

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        logger.debug("Entering ContactApplication.getSingletons()");
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyJPAJAXRS");
        ContactService contactService = new ContactService(entityManagerFactory);
        FormValueService formValueService = new FormValueService();

        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
        singletons.add(contactService);
        singletons.add(formValueService);
        logger.debug("Exiting ContactApplication.getSingletons()");
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

Also, here is the log4j properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1, LogFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Here is the logging.properties

```
com.sun.jersey.level=ALL
com.sun.jersey.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleFormatter.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Here is how I'm launching it with `mvn jetty:run`:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>java.util.logging.config.file</name>
                            <value>logging.properties</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/ManageContact</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <requestLog implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
                        <filename>target/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</filename>
                        <retainDays>90</retainDays>
                        <append>true</append>
                        <extended>true</extended>
                        <logTimeZone>GMT</logTimeZone>
                    </requestLog>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error response data, or any stacktrace on the server? This is generally a Jackson error, and by default you should get the exception error message as the response. If you have overridden this behavior, then undo it to find out the error

Comment: No, I haven't overridden anything.  I get a 400 response from cURL and nothing at all on the server.  For successful requests, I get my log messages on the console of the server.  See my edit for the Application setup, but I don't see anything that would swallow an exception and all my log messages look OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer if anyone finds this.  The issue was the servlet init in my `web.xml`.  I had to add an `init-param` to tell jersey to enable the `POJO Mapping` feature:

```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

Making the init servlet look like this:

```
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param> 
                <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name> 
                <param-value>com.webspherenotes.rest.ContactApplication</param-value> 
        </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to pass your data in below format.

{"formValues":[{"fieldName": "asdf", "fieldValue": "asdf", "fieldType": "CHAR"}]}

Comment: Nope, not it, but thanks for the answer.  That's the way to do it if you have a wrapper object that has a member that is `List<FormValue>` but I should be able to use an array.

Comment: formvalue is your custome type(class) so we need to provide name kindly try if works or not please inform

Comment: No, like I said, the method takes `FormValue[]`, which should just be a JSON array, not a JSON object like you proposed.